# Upgrade to VS2012 resulting in crash due to different VC++ runtimes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, runtime-error, msvcrt

There is a large legacy project I have to maintain, which I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012. As it is a COM server and a OCX control, creating all the typelib stuff etc. resulted in some problems that I managed to solve. However, when I run the Release build now I frequently get crashes.

I followed some advise I found here on SO and was able to track down the crash to the following piece of code:

```
int Phx2Preview::ClearOvlElementList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)m_vOvlElements.size(); i++) {
        P_SAFE_DELETE(m_vOvlElements[i].pPolyOrig);    // <- code crashes here
        P_SAFE_DELETE(m_vOvlElements[i].pPolyDispl);
    }
    m_vOvlElements.clear();
    m_vRefElemList.clear();
    m_pRefElemSelected = NULL;
    return PHXE_NO_ERROR;
}
```

`P_SAFE_DELETE` is a macro that checks if the pointer is null, and in case it's not `delete`s and sets it to null. The actual vector elements are created like this:

```
if (v1) {
    tNew.pPolyOrig = new CInPolygon();
    tNew.pPolyDispl = new CInPolygon();
    tNew.pPolyOrig->FromSafeArray(v1);
    tNew.pPolyOrig->Rotate(NULLPOINT, m_nTurnAngle*__pi/180.);
    tNew.eType = (overlayET)type;
    tNew.nImagenr = nImageNr;
    m_vOvlElements.push_back(tNew);
}
```

Now, the thing is that `CInPolygon` is a class from an external library which is created with Visual C++ 7.1. The `P_SAFE_DELETE` is also defined in a header from that library. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944589/how-bad-is-it-to-mix-and-match-vc-runtime-dlls-in-one-process) I know that mixing different runtime versions is *bad*, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959654/what-couldve-changed-in-vs-2012-to-break-my-c-application?lq=1) lets me suspect that this mixing may be responsible from the crash.

My question is: Why does it happen?  After all, since both `new` and `delete` are called from the same place, no actual objects are passed between the different CRTs. Also, when the OCX is compiled using Visual Studio 2008, no problems occur. Is this due to pure *luck*? I guess the basic issue is existing in that setting, too. And, well, what can I do to solve to problem? Switch back to VS2008?

---

**Edit**:

As asked: The destructor of `CInPolygon` is just

```
CInPolygon::~CInPolygon(void) {
  m_vPoints.clear();
}
```

here the `m_vPoints` is a `std::vector<..>` defined in the class. Maybe I should mention that `CInPolygon` inherits from that:

```
interface IRoi {
  virtual ~IRoi() {
    return;
  }
public:
  // other stuff
};
```

(Didn't even know that `interface` was a valid keyword in plain C++...) Could it be that the fact that the base class destructor is defined in the header is causing the problem? After all, that header is also known to the host programm..

Comment: immediate questions: 
- are you completely sure about the values of `i` ?
- can you show the destructor of `CInPolygon` ?

Comment: The edit to the post tells about the destructor. What do you mean concerning `i`? It's limited by the `size` of the vector I think.

Comment: Do you have source access to the CInPolygon library ? If so, try adding a 'new_CInPolygon' and a 'delete_CInPolygon' static functions, which call new and delete, but from the "correct" runtime.

Comment: I *could* do that, but I don't have VS2003 any more. I could upgrade the lib to VS2012, but then there'd no longer be a need for these functions. Nevertheless, I would be asking for trouble with my boss if I made such "time-consuming" changes to that library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  tNew.pPolyOrig = new CInPolygon();
```

Yes, this is guaranteed to fail.  Short from having different allocators in your program, your host program cannot possibly compute the size of the CInPolygon object correctly.  It uses an entirely different implementation of std::vector.  It was significantly rewritten in VS2012 to take advantage of C++11.  Inevitably, the code in the library using the old version of vector will corrupt the heap.

You **must** rebuild the library as well, using the exact same version of the compiler with the exact same settings.

Comment: So the fact that it's working if the host program is compiled with VS2008 toolset is only because `std::vector` implementations in VS2003 and VS2008 do not differ that much?

Comment: I don't have that time machine anymore to tell.  "Working" is rather a relative term when you play with undefined behavior, it is just as likely that you just never noticed a mildler version of the heap corruption before.