# run-time error "boost_log-vc100-mt-1_49.dll"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, boost-log

this may sound like a silly question, but it would be really useful if there was a way around this.

I am writing a c++ code using microsoft visual which uses eigen, matlab, and ilog cplex libraries. It can be build without problem but there is a run time error as follow:

[Translated] 
impossible to start the program because it lacks "boost_log-vc100-mt-1_49.dll".
Try reinstalling the programe for courriger this problem.

6 months ago I tried to use boost library but I gave up. After I deleted all dependencies to boost and I used Eigen without any problem. Even I can not run previous versions of my code now! Maybe I deleted a file some where?

Moreover, I tried my code on another machine and the error is the same. So, it looks it's not a system error.

I appreciate any advice you may have. 
Thank you.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2012 then you have a CRT conflict. I mean you are using boost compiled with 2010 on 2012. This is not safe.

Comment: Here is one answer that I talk about the independent heaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944589/how-bad-is-it-to-mix-and-match-vc-runtime-dlls-in-one-process/19944935#19944935

Comment: ***Even I can not run previous versions of my code now! Maybe I deleted a file some where?*** Maybe you need to create a new project that does not use boost. Or create a new project that uses the current version of boost that was compiled with Visual Studio 2012. 1.49 is pretty old. http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.57.0/ Remember that Visual Studio 2012 is msvc11 not msvc12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved! 
Matlab has some boost libraries and the link between MSV and matlab was not working though it was mentioned in linker. I copied those dll files to the current folder and now it is working.