# Can I mix different Visual C++ runtimes with a static library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, runtime-error

Regarding this Stack Overflow question: *[How bad is it to mix and match Visual C++ runtime DLL files in one process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944589/how-bad-is-it-to-mix-and-match-vc-runtime-dlls-in-one-process)*

I know I can expect heap corruption by using a different version of MSVCR at runtime.

But let's imagine the following situation that can't work:

- `libA` is a shared library which links against `MSVCR71`
- `Exe` is my program that links against `libA` and `MSVCR100`

I have then the following dependency scheme:

```
Exe +--> libA ---> MSVCR71
    +--> MSVCR100
```

**THAT is, the thing I KNOW I shouldn't do!**

BUT what if now, I compile `libA` as a static library with whatever Visual Studio that uses `MSVCR71` and I compile my program, the `Exe`, with `libA` using a Visual Studio that uses `MSCVR100`.

I will then have the following scheme:

```
Exe(lib A included) ---> MSVCR100
```

Will the program (including the static lib) be linked well against `MSVC100` without any problem? Or can I expect an **undefined behaviour** because the header of the STL are susceptible to change between the `MSVCR71` and the `MSVC100`?

Comment: A library does not "link" with anything.  It was simply compiled with outdated #include files.  Might work, you won't know until you try.  If you have source so you can recompile then there's no point in wasting your time on trying.

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing STL and standard library types between the 71 and 100 versions of the runtime - don't expect that to work. If your libraries don't share any standard library types and services (e.g. memory allocations), then you should be ok. If you have the code, save yourself the pain and just recompile everything to a single target runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer on MSDN...

I quote (*[Visual C++ change history 2003 - 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx)*):

> To avoid run-time errors that are difficult to detect and diagnose, we
>   recommend that you never statically link to binaries that were
>   compiled by using different versions of the compiler. Also, when you
>   upgrade an EXE or DLL project, make sure to upgrade the libraries that
>   it links to. If you're using CRT (C Runtime) or STL (Standard Template
>   Library) types, don't pass them between binaries (including DLLs) that
>   were compiled by using different versions of the compiler.

Hence, better recompile everything with the same compiler, to be sure.