# Linker error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary'

Tags: c++, qt, pjsip

I have some problems with pjsua2.lib. I can't build this in QT. I added the following libraries:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "$$DIRECTX_PATH\Include"
INCLUDEPATH+="$$SIP_PATH\pjsip\include"
INCLUDEPATH+="$$SIP_PATH\pjlib\include"
INCLUDEPATH+="$$SIP_PATH\pjlib-util\include"
INCLUDEPATH+="$$SIP_PATH\pjnath\include"
INCLUDEPATH+="$$SIP_PATH\pjmedia\include"
INCLUDEPATH+="$$SIP_PATH\pjsip-apps\src\pjsua\pjsua_app.h"
INCLUDEPATH+="$$SIP_PATH\pjsip\src\pjsua-lib\pjsua_acc.c"
LIBS += "$$DIRECTX_PATH\Lib\x86\dsound.lib"
LIBS += "$$DIRECTX_PATH\Lib\x86\dxguid.lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\WS2_32.Lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\Ole32.Lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\WSock32.Lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\IPHlpApi.Lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\NetAPI32.Lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\AdvAPI32.Lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\Gdi32.Lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\User32.Lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\odbccp32.lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\odbc32.lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\msvfw32.Lib"
LIBS+="$$WINDOWS_SDKS_PATH\Lib\Version.Lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\lib\libpjproject-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjsip\lib\pjsip-core-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjsip\lib\pjsip-simple-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjsip\lib\pjsip-ua-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjsip\lib\pjsua2-lib-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjsip\lib\pjsua-lib-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjlib\lib\pjlib-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjlib-util\lib\pjlib-util-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjmedia\lib\pjmedia-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjnath\lib\pjnath-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\third_party\lib\libbaseclasses-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\third_party\lib\libg7221codec-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\third_party\lib\libgsmcodec-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\third_party\lib\libilbccodec-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\third_party\lib\libmilenage-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\third_party\lib\libportaudio-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\third_party\lib\libresample-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\third_party\lib\libspeex-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\third_party\lib\libsrtp-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjmedia\lib\pjmedia-audiodev-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
LIBS+="$$SIP_PATH\pjmedia\lib\pjmedia-codec-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib"
```

but these errors show up whenever I try to build the application:

```
pjsua2-lib-i386-Win32-vc8-Debug.lib(endpoint.obj):-1: error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj
```

I think the problem comes from the compiler, but in any way, I can't seem to solve it

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14714877/675646 and others.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the library you are linking to has been build with a different version / variant of the CRT (C Runtime). You either need to rebuild the library or set the runtime library version + variant (release/debug, DLL/static) in your projects properties to the same settings as all the libraries you are linking to.