# LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary' with cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

I am compiling a dynamic library containing cpp with cu files with Visual Studio 2013, and I get such errors during linking:

```
proj_generated_cufile.cu.obj : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in file.obj
libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in file.obj
```

I am not using any additional libraries, and I have already tried to set the Runtime Library in the project preferences -> C/C++ -> Code generation to "Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)" and under CUDA C/C++ -> Host to "Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)" or to "inherit from host".

I am generating the project with cmake (with cuda_add_library).

Can it be, that the problem is, that I am trying to compile a dynamic library? What contradicts this assumption is that when I am compiling only the cpp files the compilation succeeds.

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14714877/681865

Comment: Thank you, but I am not linking any additional libraries.

Comment: But you are - the VS C++ runtime library, and that is where the build settings mismatch is occurring

Comment: Oh I have found the problem, the CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS was set to OFF in the cmake file.... Thank you guys, and sorry.

Comment: In my case, I had to use MDd/MD flags instead of MT/MTd flags in cmake, compile and generate again along with CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS = 1. Changing to Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD) or Multi-Threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) in Visual Studio was not propagating host flags.

Answer (score 2):

I think , one was linked against the CRT DLL (/MD) and the other was linked statically (/MT).

Comment: Thank you, but I am compiling only one project to a dynamic library (for which is set /MD), and I am not linking any other additional libraries.

Comment: Look into your project files carefully please.