# gmock and gtest linker errors in vc++ 2015 community edition

Tags: visual-c++, googlemock

I'm tyring to configure **gmock/gtest** in vc++ 2015, namely

1. downloaded gmock and gtest
2. added   E:\googlemock\googletest\include and E:\googlemock\googlemock\include in VC++ include directories.
3. compiled gmock.sln and added E:\googlemock\googlemock\msvc\2015\Debug to the Library directories.
4. added gmock.lib to Linker -> Input Additional dependencies.

And on building I'm getting a bunch of linker errors as below.

**As i don't have any clue about the gmock/ gtest code. How shall I reason / proceed further in fixing these problems ?**

code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

```
Error   **LNK2038** mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in ArrayOperations.obj   ConsoleApplication3 E:\projects\cpp\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\gmock.lib(gtest-all.obj)    
Error   **LNK2005** "public: bool __thiscall std::ios_base::good(void)const " (?good@ios_base@std@@QBE_NXZ) already defined in gmock.lib(gtest-all.obj) ConsoleApplication3 E:\projects\cpp\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP140D.dll) 1
```

and more bunch of errors on the same LNK category*

Comment: If you are using VisualStudio with CMake, this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70398280/980270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem by adding in properties -> c++ code generation

Run time Library to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) as from the post.

[Mismatch Detected for 'RuntimeLibrary'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714877/mismatch-detected-for-runtimelibrary)