# GoogleTest compile with MT_StaticRelease errors

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

How can I force google test compile with /MT option?
I saw that google test tries to compile with MT(internal_utils.cmake line 33):

```
  if (NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS AND NOT gtest_force_shared_crt)
    string(REPLACE "/MD" "-MT" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
  endif()
```

But it doesn't work (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS and gtest_force_shared_crt are disabled).
I gets error when my project compiles with MT:

> gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for
> "RuntimeLibrary": value "MD_DynamicRelease" does not match value
> "MT_StaticRelease"

And more some LNK2005 and LNK4217.
If I try to compile my project without MT, all compiles ok.
How can I solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The proper way to set the MSVC runtime in CMake (versions 3.15 and greater) is by using [`MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/prop_tgt/MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html), as seen in the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56776146/3987854).

Comment: @squareskittles, do I need to do this for the "gtest" target?

Answer (score 6):

That `if` is a test, implementing a switch allowing *you* to configure it *before* including googletest.

It's also mentioned in the [manual](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/README.md#visual-studio-dynamic-vs-static-runtimes):

> **Visual Studio Dynamic vs Static Runtimes**
>
> By default, new Visual Studio projects link the C runtimes dynamically
> but GoogleTest links them statically. This will generate an error that
> looks something like the following: *gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error
> LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value
> 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj*
>
> GoogleTest already has a CMake option for this: **`gtest_force_shared_crt`**
>
> Enabling this option will make gtest link the runtimes dynamically
> too, and match the project in which it is included.

So just set it in your project e.g. like this:

```
set(gtest_force_shared_crt on)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(googletest
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
        GIT_TAG main)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()
```