# Liink error building Googletest project in Visual Studio with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, googletest

I have a Visual Studio CMake project. This is the CMakeListst.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)
project(googletest-cmake)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(googletest
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest
    GIT_TAG release-1.11.0)
FetchContent_GetProperties(googletest)
if(NOT googletest_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(googletest)
  add_subdirectory(${googletest_SOURCE_DIR} ${googletest_BUILD_DIR})
endif()

add_executable (CMakeProject4 "CMakeProject4.cpp" )
target_link_libraries(CMakeProject4 PRIVATE gtest_main)
```

The CMakeProject4.cpp file is trivial:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(TestSuiteSample, TestSample)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(6, 1+5);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

When I run "Build", this is the error I get:
`Error  LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in test.obj  testRunner  C:\GTestWithCMakeFetchContent\VSBuild\gmock_maind.lib(gtest-all.obj)`   1
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: The error message looks like ... it is about **other project**. It mentions `test.obj` file and `gmock_main` library, but you neither have a source named `test` nor you use `gmock` (gtest is not gmock).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this too and think I found the culprit.

Try adding this to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
```

The [GoogleTest release notes](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/README.md#visual-studio-dynamic-vs-static-runtimes) include the following:

```
##### Visual Studio Dynamic vs Static Runtimes

By default, new Visual Studio projects link the C runtimes dynamically but
GoogleTest links them statically. This will generate an error that looks
something like the following: gtest.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch
detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value
'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj

GoogleTest already has a CMake option for this: `gtest_force_shared_crt`

Enabling this option will make gtest link the runtimes dynamically too, and
match the project in which it is included.
```

See also:

- [GoogleTest compile with MT_StaticRelease errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925255/googletest-compile-with-mt-staticrelease-errors)
- [How to make GTest build /MDd (instead of /MTd) by default, using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540970/how-to-make-gtest-build-mdd-instead-of-mtd-by-default-using-cmake)